# Magento 2 "Place order" button not working with stripe and One Step Checkout Amasty

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout, stripe

I've integrated Stripe (its official module, latest version 2.1.4) as payment method along One Step Checkout from Amasty in Magento 2.3.5.

Something seems wrong as "Place order" button is not working. "Place order" button is clickable, but nothing happens. When I select another payment method, it works fine. But selecting "Stripe" as payment method it don't.

If I disable One Step Checkout, it also works fine (including Stripe).

So the problem is between Stripe module and One Step Checkout from Amasty. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Please check in your console, may be there you have some JS error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known integration issue between the two modules. Amasty has been notified about the issue and they are currently working on a fix.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there might be a conflict between the Stripe module and the One Step Checkout module from Amasty. Here are some suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue:

- Check for any Javascript errors: Open up the browser console and check for any Javascript errors that might be causing the issue. If there are any errors related to Stripe or One Step Checkout, try to fix them accordingly.
- Disable other payment methods: Disable all other payment methods except for Stripe and see if the "Place order" button works. If it works, then there might be a conflict between Stripe and another payment method.
- Check for conflicts with other modules: Disable all other third-party modules except for Stripe and One Step Checkout and see if the "Place order" button works. If it works, then there might be a conflict with another module. Try enabling each module one by one to identify which one is causing the issue.
- Contact support: If the above steps do not resolve the issue, contact the support team for both Stripe and Amasty One Step Checkout. They might be able to provide more insight into the issue and offer a solution.

Overall, it is not uncommon for there to be conflicts between different modules in Magento, especially when it comes to payment methods. However, with some troubleshooting and support, it should be possible to resolve the issue and get Stripe working with One Step Checkout.